# LeetCode: Sort The Matrix Diagonally C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-the-matrix-diagonally/

[image]

> A matrix diagonal is a diagonal line of cells starting from some cell
> in either the topmost row or leftmost column and going in the
> bottom-right direction until reaching the matrix's end. For example,
> the matrix diagonal starting from mat[2][0], where mat is a 6 x 3
> matrix, includes cells mat[2][0], mat[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAUac.png), and mat[4][2].
>
> Given an m x n matrix mat of integers, sort each matrix diagonal in
> ascending order and return the resulting matrix.

my idea is to run as a BFS on the matrix. each cell visit top and right cells. to form a diagonal and sort it.

please review for performance. it took 30 mins to write the code. review this please as this is a coding interview.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-the-matrix-diagonally/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class MatrixDiagonalSortTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            int[][] input = { new[] { 3, 3, 1, 1 }, new[] { 2, 2, 1, 2 }, new[] { 1, 1, 1, 2 } };
            int[][] output = { new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new[] { 1, 2, 2, 2 }, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 3 } };
            var res = DiagonalSort(input);
            for (int r = 0; r < res.Length; r++)
            {
                CollectionAssert.AreEqual(output[r], res[r]);
            }
            
        }
        public int[][] DiagonalSort(int[][] mat)
        {
            Queue<Cell> Q = new Queue<Cell>();
            Q.Enqueue(new Cell(mat.Length-1, 0, mat[mat.Length-1][0]));
            while (Q.Count > 0)
            {
                List<Cell> tempList = new List<Cell>();
                int count = Q.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    var curr = Q.Dequeue();
                    tempList.Add(curr);
                    int newR = curr.r - 1;
                    int newC = curr.c;
                    if (newR >= 0)//go up
                    {
                        if (Q.FirstOrDefault(x => x.r == newR && x.c == newC) == null)
                        {
                            Q.Enqueue(new Cell(newR, newC, mat[newR][newC]));
                        }

                    }
                    newR = curr.r;
                    newC = curr.c + 1;
                    if (newC <= mat[0].Length - 1)//go right
                    {
                        if (Q.FirstOrDefault(x => x.r == newR && x.c == newC) == null)
                        {
                            Q.Enqueue(new Cell(newR, newC, mat[newR][newC]));
                        }
                    }
                }
                var listValues = new List<int>();
                foreach (var item in tempList)
                {
                    listValues.Add(item.v);
                }
                listValues.Sort();
                for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count; i++)
                {
                    mat[tempList[i].r][tempList[i].c] = listValues[i];
                }
            }
            return mat;
        }
    }
    [DebuggerDisplay("r ={r}, c={c}, v={v}")]
    public class Cell
    {
        public Cell(int r1, int c1, int v1)
        {
            r = r1;
            c = c1;
            v = v1;

        }
        public int r { get; set; }
        public int c { get; set; }
        public int v { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few tips

1. For code quality, consider to give variables/fields more understandeable names.
2. For immutable `Cell` fields add `readonly`, it may affect the performance.
3. If you know how many items will be put in the collection, construct it with capacity `new List<Cell>(count)`, `capacity` means initial size for the underlying storage not max items limit.
4. `FirstOrDefault == null` can be replaced with `!Any`.
5. You may add items directly to `listValues` i guess, and optimize out `tempList` or vice-versa. Then Sort by field with Linq, or custom comparer, or implement `IComparable` for `Cell`.
6. `Cell` can be `struct`? If yes, you can try to take an advantage of stack allocations (for small amount of data) instead of heap using `Span<T>`-related optimizations.

For 5th tip, this code (as far as I got the idea)

```cs
var listValues = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in tempList)
{
    listValues.Add(item.v);
}
listValues.Sort();
for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count; i++)
{
    mat[tempList[i].r][tempList[i].c] = listValues[i];
}
```

Can be optimized as

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in tempList.OrderBy(x => x.v))
{
    mat[tempList[i].r][tempList[i].c] = item.v;
    i++;
}
```

*Btw, I've tested various optimizations from listed above and more but got only insignificant performance boost. The slowest point is here `FirstOrDefault(x => x.r == newR && x.c == newC)`. I have no idea how to improve it without moving the solution to different approach.*

Ok, let's do it.

```cs
public int[][] DiagonalSort(int[][] mat)
{
    int width = mat[0].Length;
    int height = mat.Length;
    List<int> values = new List<int>(height);
    for (int j = 2 - height; j < width - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            int offset = j + i;
            if (offset >= 0 && offset < width)
                values.Add(mat[i][offset]);
        }
        values.Sort();
        for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            int offset = j + i;
            if (offset >= 0 && offset < width)
                mat[i][offset] = values[count++];
        }
        values.Clear();
    }
    return mat;
}
```

~15% faster than initial solution.

Comment: thanks for taking the time!